# How can I pack my potted plants for moving (across the US)?

Tags: containers, pots

I'm faced with moving across the US soon.

As my climate zone will be changing, some of my outdoor potted plants will have to become indoor plants. However, I would like to take as many as possible with me.

How can I best pack plants for travel? I have a mixture of sizes: some are in 6" pots and some over 7' tall (I'm particularly concerned about the latter), with several dozen pots in between. Maybe techniques are different for each.

How can I keep the soil intact and not making a mess of my truck and other belongings? Are there clever techniques for keeping plants from getting crushed? I'll likely have a moving truck and my car.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This page](http://moving.about.com/od/movingityourself/a/moving_plants.htm) offered some good advice.

Basically:

- Any breakable ceramic pots, try placing them in an open-toped box, cushioned with bubble-wrap or a towel or something to protect the pot.
- If possible, replant into plastic containers so they don't break.
- Anything tall, wrap it in some bubble wrap or plastic to protect it.  Also make sure it has some holes to breathe.  I might worry about too much contact with the plastic if it's too wet, so be careful there.
- You also have to be careful if you're moving from one state to another.  You aren't allowed to bring some plants across different state lines.  For instance, Arizona does not allow citrus from outside the state.

If you were moving to a place with harsher sun, I would suggest marking the plant's positioning, but it sounds like you're moving somewhere cooler, so I don't imagine that will be a problem.

You might consider trimming some of the larger plants, if they can handle that.  Depending on the length of your journey, you might consider packing the plants into your moving truck last so that you can water them if necessary.