# How can I help my plants adjust after moving apartments?

Tags: houseplants

[This question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/how-can-i-pack-my-potted-plants-for-moving-across-the-us) details how to prepare plants for actually moving, but I am interested in knowing how I can help my plants adjust once they are actually in the new residence, especially with regards to moving apartments.

I have several houseplants (pothos, philodenron, monstera, etc. most exotic is a young medinilla magnifica) that are currently enjoying my west-facing windows. My new residence will only have north facing windows. What can I do before and after my move to help them adjust?

Comment: I don't think you'll have to do much, just treat them like always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the plants you list will do okay with indirect sunlight, and in fact will not enjoy too much direct sun as it can scorch the leaves. Fortunately most popular house plants can tolerate lower light levels well (that's why they're popular house plants!).

Having said that, give them as much light as you can when you do move, and perhaps reserve the brightest spot for the medinilla magnifica. Keep an eye on them and if they don't look happy, try changing their position if you think that is what is causing the problem.

If they're in a cooler, darker spot, they may not need quite as much water as they have done previously, so take care to avoid overwatering.

Comment: Would a plant light help for the medinilla, or any plant that doesn't take well to the drop in direct light?

Comment: I would try it without to start with and see how they do. A plant light could be an option if they don't seem to be doing well, but I'm not sure there's any real substitute for actual sunlight...